# How to copy rows from the excel to the datagridxl

Tags: javascript

When I try to copy the rows from excel to the datagridxl(https://www.datagridxl.com/), the row is not increasing automatically.
If someone knows how to fix it, please help me.

Comment: DataGridXL unfortunately does not feature variable row heights. This decision was made to keep the performance optimal.

Comment: Or did you mean that DataGridXL should add rows automatically when something is pasted from Excel? We'll have that in version 2.

Comment: That's correct.  If yes, let me try to use version 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of DataGridXL (version 2), you can use the option `expandSheetOnPaste` (which is `true` by default):

```
<div id="grid" style="height:400px;"></div>

<script src="https://code.datagridxl.com/datagridxl2.js"></script>
<script>
  var grid = new DataGridXL("grid", {
    expandSheetOnPaste: true
  });
</script>
```

If you copy rows from Excel to your DataGridXL instance, rows should automatically be added.